# Running out of memory during evaluation in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I'm training a model in pytorch. Every 10 epochs, I'm evaluating the train and test error on the entire train and test dataset. For some reason the evaluation function is causing out-of-memory on my GPU. This is strange because I have the same batchsize for training and evaluation. I believe it's due to the net.forward() method being called repeated and having all the hidden values stored in memory but I'm not sure how to get around this?

```
def evaluate(self, data):
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    loader = self.train_loader if data == "train" else self.test_loader
    for step, (story, question, answer) in enumerate(loader):
        story = Variable(story)
        question = Variable(question)
        answer = Variable(answer)
        _, answer = torch.max(answer, 1)

        if self.config.cuda:
            story = story.cuda()
            question = question.cuda()
            answer = answer.cuda()

        pred_prob = self.mem_n2n(story, question)[0]
        _, output_max_index = torch.max(pred_prob, 1)
        toadd = (answer == output_max_index).float().sum().data[0]
        correct = correct + toadd
        total = total + captions.size(0)

    acc = correct / total
    return acc
```

Comment: Please share the data loading part.

Answer (score 16):

I think it fails during Validation because you don't use `optimizer.zero_grad()`. The zero_grad executes `detach`, making the tensor a leaf. It is commonly used every epoch in the training part.

The use of volatile flag in Variable from PyTorch 0.4.0 has been removed.
Ref - [migration_guide_to_0.4.0](https://pytorch.org/2018/04/22/0_4_0-migration-guide.html)

Starting from 0.4.0, to avoid the gradient being computed during validation, use torch.no_grad()

Code example from the migration guide.

```
# evaluate
with torch.no_grad():                   # operations inside don't track history
  for input, target in test_loader:
      ...
```

For 0.3.X, using volatile should work.

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest to use **volatile** flag set to **True** for all variables used during the evaluation,

```
    story = Variable(story, volatile=True)
    question = Variable(question, volatile=True)
    answer = Variable(answer, volatile=True)
```

Thus, the gradients and operation history is not stored and you will save a lot of memory.
Also, you could delete references to those variables at the end of the batch processing:

```
del story, question, answer, pred_prob
```

Don't forget to set the model to the evaluation mode (and back to the train mode after you finished the evaluation). For instance, like this

```
model.eval()
```